Site is Indexed by Google. But not listed in Google Search
Introduction
I have a site that has pages that are already indexed by Google, but the page is somehow not available in google search.
Google Search Console
Google search console indicates that the site is already listed:

Google Search
However, when checking google search for site:petcoach.sg. We are unable to find the site:

Thank you
Thanks, let me know what other information I can include to help troubleshoot this issue.

When I do the search, the page appears 27th in the results.
Google load the results asynchronously, so inspecting the source will not show you all the results in their database.

Hey @RichardB,
Thanks for your prompt response. However, I've double checked and it's still not showing up.
I've checked by running the following search query: site:petcoach.sg/canine-conditioning-coach-unleashing-your-dogs-full-physical-potential/

That also appears for me.  There may be a location-based issue - I'm in the UK.  If the site is new, it may just not be fully indexed.  If not, I guess there may possibly be false-positive censorship going on, depending on your location.

Noted with thanks, it has appeared now when I checked again using the same search query site:petcoach.sg/canine-conditioning-coach-unleashing-your-dogs-full-physical-potential/
